# Social Network Plugin doesn't login

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, social-networking, prime31

I use SocialNetwork Plugin for Android from Prime31 (here) in my project for facebook.
If I use demo scene - all work good. If I in single window create 3 buttons (init, login, share) it also work good. But if I use `FacebookAndroid.init()` in first update (or `Awake` or `Start`) and login in some window of my game - after login to FB window session isn't valid and I Can't share anything.

List of my Facebook Controller:

```
public class FacebookController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static FacebookController instance;

    void Awake ()
    {
        instance = this;
    }

    private bool isFirst = true;
    void Update () 
    {
        if (isFirst)
        {
            isFirst = false;
#if UNITY_ANDROID
            FacebookAndroid.init();
#endif
        }
    }

    public void Login()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        var permissions = new string[] { "publish_actions", "publish_stream" };


FacebookAndroid.setSessionLoginBehavior(FacebookSessionLoginBehavior.SUPPRESS_SSO);
        FacebookAndroid.loginWithPublishPermissions(permissions);

#endif
    }

    public void Logoff()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        FacebookAndroid.logout();
#endif
    }

    public bool IsLogged()
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        FacebookAndroid.isSessionValid();
#endif
        return false;
    }

    public void Share(string name, string message)
    {
#if UNITY_ANDROID
        if (FacebookAndroid.isSessionValid())
        {
            var parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                { "link", "http://prime31.com" },
                { "name", name },
                { "picture", "http://prime31.com/assets/images/prime31logo.png" },
                { "caption", message }
            };
            FacebookAndroid.showFacebookShareDialog(parameters);
        }
#endif
    }
}
```